# Gatsby/React useEffect hook versus "typeof window"

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Can the `useEffect()` hook perform the same function as `typeof window !== 'undefined';`, whereby determining the availability of a browser window?

Comment: No window is not a property, useEffect can't watch it. If anything references `window.` without the check will blow up Gatsby.

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` hook triggers initially after the component output has been rendered to the DOM. Therefore it is not exclusive to check the availability of the `window` because it may not be defined yet. You should check for the `window` regardless if you use `useEffect` or not.

You can check for further information about `useEffect` hook in [React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).